# Real time console output in application via trace

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, flex4.5

Is it somehow possible to output the traces in a deployed application to a display element?
I'm aware of the debug deploy in Flash Builder, but unfortunately I can't convince my iPad to work with that, so a real time trace output in my application would be really great.

Edit: On second thought, a full console output would probably be best. The flash console kostik suggested looks pretty good, so making it display the console output would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/flash-console/

Comment: That looks promising, although I can't get it to display the standard AS traces. Cc.config.tracing is set to true, though.

Comment: Also you can try http://demonsterdebugger.com. But in this case you will need use code MonsterDebugger.trace(...). In order to handle native FlashPlayer traces you need debug Flash Player.

Answer (score 1):

Highly recomend monsterdebugger and flash-console however sometimes you just need to integration offered by an ide. Flash develop has some nice debugging features however I have come to love Intellij Idea's new features for flash debugging. Here is a peek of some recent gems http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/12/features-of-flex-debugger/